# Modifying unselected branches in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to modify a node in a branch depending on it's sibling. In the following example, I want to add `<var2 Value='D'/>` to the pre-existing `<nest2>` if `nest1` contains `<var1 Value='A'>`.

**Input:**

```
<variables>
  <nest1>
    <var1 Value='A'/>
    <var1 Value='B'/>
  </nest1>
  <nest2>
    <var2 Value='C'/>
  </nest2>
</variables>
```

**Output**

```
<variables>
  <nest1>
    <var1 Value='A'/>
    <var1 Value='B'/>
  </nest1>
  <nest2>
    <var2 Value='C'/>
    <var2 Value='D'/>
  </nest2>
</variables>
```

I can match `<var1 Value='A'/>`, but I don't know how to modify the pre-existing `<nest2>`. I can match `<nest2>`, but I don't know how to check to see if `<var1 Value='A'/>` exists in `<nest1>`. I'm just stumped on where to go from here.

I am using xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet that should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nest2[preceding-sibling::nest1/var1[@Value = 'A']]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <var2 Value="D"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: When I tried that stylesheet, it removed `<var2 Value='C'/>` and replaced it with `<var2 Value='D'/>`. Edit: Nevermind - the error was on my end. Thanks!